# Disable text selection on a button in mobile but keeping the ontouchstart functionality

Tags: html, css

I have a button that the user can press and hold to record their voice. The problem is that on mobile when I press and hold the button, the button text gets selected. If I disable text selection, apparently the `ontouchstart` event is not triggered. How to achieve both?

Comment: would it be possible to create a `span` or `div` that holds the text inside the `button` and then remove the `pointer events`/`touch-action` on that element?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti Thanks, I'll try that. I was assuming there would be a more straightforward solution as this is a fairly common scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the `user-select: none` css property on that elemet

Comment: As explained in the post, this seems to prevent `ontouchstart` event.